# Not able to connect to SQL container using service sqlservice. Not able to figure out problem. Everything looks fine

Tags: kubernetes

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secretssql
                  key: pass
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysqlvolume
              mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
      volumes:
        - name: mysqlvolume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: sqlpvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secretssql
data:
  # You can include additional key value pairs as you do with Opaque Secrets
  pass: YWRtaW4=

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqlservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - port: 80
```

### I want to connect to sql container using service sqlservice. Dns is reachable but when I try to ping the service,100% packet loss.

I want to connect to sql container using service sqlservice. Dns is reachable but when I try to ping the service,100% packet loss.I want to connect to sql container using service sqlservice.

Comment: What's the actual host name you're trying to connect to?  Where are you trying to connect from?  What's the error you're getting?  (Use a client like `mysql`; don't use  a tool like `ping` that sends packets using a different protocol.)

Answer (score 1):

Your service is using port 80:

```
  ports:
    - port: 80
```

while your pod is listening on port 3306:

```
ports:
  - containerPort: 3306
```

Try adjusting your service to user port 3306:

```
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```